# How to get current URL (including path) in Heroku custom error page

Tags: html, heroku, url, iframe, error-handling

I have followed these instructions to set-up a custom Heroku error page: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-pages#customize-pages

What I'm trying to do is, in this `error-page.html`, get the current URL that was accessed (e.g. `"https://my-domain.com/page3"`), so that I can use this `"page3"` information to redirect the user further.

The problem is that the "https://bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/**error-page.html**" is displayed inside an `<iframe>` by Heroku, which doesnt have access to the current URL. (it may have access via different ways to only `"my-domain.com"`, without the path `"/page3"`).

What I have tried are the following:

**document.referrer**: gives correct url but without `/page3`

**document.location.href**: gives my own (AWS URL of error-page.html)

**window.parent.location**: inaccessible due to security

**document.location.ancestorOrigins[0]**: gives correct url but without `/page3`

1. Is there any way to get this information from inside the iFrame?
2. Is there any other (Heroku) way that I can know the current URL when my app crashes so I can redirect the user somewhere useful?